# Make Windows 7/8 to use different partitions for system data and user/program data

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, partitioning, backup

Is there the way to mount partition as /Users, while first one mounted as root (where /Windows folder lives)?

I want to be able to make backup image of system excepting all user/program data (like saves in game, photos, program settings, et cetera).

But there is another folder - /ProgramData, which I don't want to store in backup. So I need to make another partition for it?

In the internet I found solution, that makes /Users and /ProgamData to live in another "drive". And it has disadvantage, because some programs has hardcoded path to C:/Users or C:/ProgramData.